# Specific Function Generation

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble finding a function that is decreasing at $x=-6$ while also having a local maximum of $x=2$ and minima of $x=-2$. I keep ending up with the wrong equation and the closest I've gotten is $\sin(-1/2x)$ which I know I'm wrong. I'm sorry for the stupid question but I'm confused and my tutor is busy

Comment: What about $y=-\frac{1}{3}x^3 +4x$?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=\begin {cases}
-x-6; x\le -2\\ x-2; -2\lt x\le 2\\ -x+2; x\gt 2  \end{cases}$

$f'(-6)\lt 0$ and hence decreasing at $x=-6$ 
$f(-2)=-4$, which is a local minimum as you can verify and $f(2)$ is local maxima.